# Can I get a global RSS feed of all my activity?

Tags: feature-request, support, global-inbox, feed

Can I get a global RSS feed of all my activity?

I see how to do the for a single site with

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/656912/raxacoricofallapatorius?tab=activity
```

but this appears not to work globally, at least not with the obvious analog:

```
http://stackexchange.com/users/331923/raxacoricofallapatorius?tab=activity
```

I'm aware that there are *many* posts about this already, and many seeming solutions, but I've tried all that I can find, but none that I've found are recent, and *none* work as described.

Comment: Why do you want this? I only ask because perhaps there's already a solution out there for what you need, and maybe RSS isn't the actual option to take (See: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @JonW: I'd like something I can use in [Reeder](http://reederapp.com) or in [Safari Subscriptions](http://osxdaily.com/2014/11/03/subscribe-rss-feeds-safari-os-x/) — i.e., something that integrates with all my other fees from all sources across all devices.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: No: 2012.